# Detecting outlook 2007 client in email

Tags: email, outlook

Is it possible to detect the email client in an html message? Specifically outlook 2007

**Update**

My users have access to an online system that really has nothing to do with email, but in this system they can all communicate with themselves.

My app - takes messages from this system, and then sends it via an email instead.

Now I need a reply to function. Obviously its not a normal email address so...

I want a way to intercept this message, and send it via another channel.

I could write the outlook plug to check EVERY SINGLE out going email address, but this surely can't be the way we're expected to work with email.

It would be much easier to have a button in the email itself which can call an outlook function (custom) and then pass control to this function.

**Uodate**

Thanks guys for your answer, but there is a little more complexity. The online system contains fields, these fields need to be completed by the user before sending the reply. So I need some kind of form (yes with working check boxes, etc in there). This should all be in the email message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially what you'll need to do is set up an automated process that monitors a particular email address, and set that address as the `reply-to` in your outgoing email. When a message comes in, you can do whatever analysis you need to (examining the `from`, subject, etc.) and process the content however you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

"Detect" using what? Javascript does not work in email. CSS stylesheets don't either - so no CSS hacks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Meaning why do you care whether it's outlook or not _within_ your email?

Comment: @JL: I would definitely NOT classify disabling Javascript in email as a "shortfall".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the *Reply-To* header in the email to the direction that you want?

You have an example in C# & VB in: http://www.systemwebmail.com/faq/2.7.aspx